# Repeat elements from one array based on another

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing

Given

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
b = np.array(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'])

c = np.array([1,1,1,4,4,4,8,8])
```

where a & b 'correspond' to each other, how can I use c to slice b to get d which 'corresponds' to c:

```
d = np.array(['a','a','a','d','d','d','h','h')]
```

I know how to do this by looping

```
for n in range(a.shape[0]):
    d[n] = b[np.argmax(a==c[n])]
```

but want to know if I can do this without loops.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `a` always of the form `1,2,3...`?

Comment: Not necessarily, could have repeating values, but a , b, c & d always have the same length

Comment: So if `a` has `1,1` and `b` has `'a','b'`, how do you choose?

Comment: Then it doensn't matter if 'a' or 'b' is chosen

Answer (score 0):

With the `a` that is just position+1 you can simply use

```
In [33]: b[c - 1]
Out[33]: array(['a', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'h', 'h'], dtype='<U1')
```

I'm tempted to leave it at that, since the `a` example isn't enough to distinguish it from the `argmax` approach.

But we can test all `a` against all `c` with:

```
In [36]: a[:,None]==c
Out[36]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True]])
In [37]: (a[:,None]==c).argmax(axis=0)
Out[37]: array([0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7])
In [38]: b[_]
Out[38]: array(['a', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'h', 'h'], dtype='<U1')
```